# WSS3.0 to SharePoint Foundation 2010 upgrade

Tags: sharepoint, wss-3.0, sharepoint-2010, migration

I've got a Windows 2003 x86 server with a small WSS3.0 installation. Now we've bought a new server with Windows Server 2008 x64 and installed SharePoint Foundation 2010 on it. I wish to transfer the few lists and their view from the old WSS3 to SP2010.

How should I do this? All the migration websites I've read talk about preparing, but no-one really say how to migrate from one x86 2007 server to a x64 2010 server.

Cheers

Nik

Answer (score 4):

You will want to do what is called a "database attach upgrade" of your 2007 data. The basic outline of what happens is that you:

- setup your SharePoint 2010 farm (make sure that all the settings are setup how you want them, and that you include all custom/3rd party solutions and web parts)
- backup your SharePoint 2007 database(s)
- restore your database(s) to the SharePoint 2010 Database
- Add your new database/site to the SharePoint 2010 farm using the command:

  stsadm -o addcontentdb -url <URL> -databasename <database name>
  (this will upgrade your database to the 2010 format at the same time)
- Upgrade the site(s) to use the new SharePoint 2010 interface

Here are 2 blog posts that walk you through the database attach upgrade procedure:
http://sharepointgeorge.com/2009/upgrading-content-db-sharepoint-2010-part-1-preupgradecheck/
http://sharepointgeorge.com/2009/upgrading-content-database-sharepoint-2010-database-attach-method/

Also, check out [this chart](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=e8b66eb3-27c7-4a39-a2e1-3e7d18b12ee1) from Microsoft to see all of the available upgrade options.

Comment: Thank you very much! :-) Just a short question, since this is a small site running WSS, it uses SQL Server Express (default when WSS3 was set up). How should I back up this database. There is no SQL Management Studio for that, right? And the SharePoint 2010 Foundation didn't have a SQL Server 2008 pre-installed, so I expect it has also deployed an SQL Server Express instance, how should I restore to this one? Are there any tools you could recommend? Finally, for this upgrade option, does it include my views?

Comment: This is actually a free version of SQL Server Management studio available for both 2005 and 2008. 

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=C243A5AE-4BD1-4E3D-94B8-5A0F62BF7796&displaylang=en

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=08e52ac2-1d62-45f6-9a4a-4b76a8564a2b&displaylang=en

Comment: Thanks a bunch, I'll try that out first thing monday :-)

Comment: Thanks from me to, I'd also found the TechNet prep, but no actual doing it

Answer (score 0):

1.Prepare a server with x64 windows 2003
2.Install x64 windows 2003 ;
3.Use stsadm.exe commander to migrate x86 wss3.0 to x64 wss3.0;
4.Upgrade the server with x64 windows 2003 to x64 windows 2008 R2
5.Upgrade the X64 WSS3.0 TO X64 SharePoint Foundation 2010.

Answer (score 0):

As I posted in another thread, Robert Crane from CIAOPS is a Sharepoint guru and has posted a series of steps to migrate data from WSS3.0 to Sharepoint Foundation Server 2010 on his blog. I used them the other week to migrate 2 different clients to SFS2010. Worked flawlessly!

It's posted in 15 different sections so I'll give you the link to the last one that has all of his previous steps listed in order. Hope it helps you!

http://supportweb.ciaops.net.au/blog/archive/2010/11/21/migration-by-the-numbers-%E2%80%93-step-15.aspx

I know it says it's for SBS2008, but tbh, that doesn't matter. If you find something that is specific to SBS, ignore it and carry on.

As always, make sure you've got a backup/rollback plan in place before you start anything.

To provide a little more detail from some of your followup questions, you can access your SQL Express database through Management Studio Express quite easily. My boss posted how to access iton our blog a while back: http://www.grassrootsit.com.au/2011/blog/shrinking-sharepoint-wss-database-and-log-files/

Step 3 is probably the most relevant to your interests (although, I'd recommend making sure that your logfiles haven't bloated up too badly ;)).