# Moving WSS sites to a new SharePoint 2010 Foundation server

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, wss-3.0

This [existing question](https://serverfault.com/questions/113714/wss3-0-to-sharepoint-foundation-2010-upgrade) helps but it doesn't answer all my questions.

I have WSS 3 running on Server1 (Server 2003) and its database is DBServer1 (SQL 2008). I have installed SharePoint 2010 Foundation on Server2 (Server 2008) with databases on DBServer2 (SQL 2008 R2).

SP 2010 Foundation is up and running ok and it already has one newly created Web Application. Now my goal is to copy all sites from Server1/DBServer1 to Server2/DBServer2 (and eventually retire Server1/DBServer1).

Could you please help me with a step-by-step list on how to accomplish this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Robert Crane from CIAOPS is a Sharepoint guru and has posted a series of steps to migrate data from WSS3.0 to Sharepoint Foundation Server 2010 on his blog. I used them the other week to migrate 2 different clients to SFS2010. Worked flawlessly!

It's posted in 15 different sections so I'll give you the link to the last one that has all of his previous steps listed in order. Hope it helps you!

http://supportweb.ciaops.net.au/blog/archive/2010/11/21/migration-by-the-numbers-%E2%80%93-step-15.aspx

I know it says it's for SBS2008, but tbh, that doesn't matter. If you find something that is specific to SBS, ignore it and carry on.

As always, make sure you've got a backup/rollback plan in place before you start anything.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has fairly exhaustive [set of documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/ee517215) on how to do it.

I just did a similar migration last week.  Depending on your availability requirements, this can be as simple as (detach/attach method):

- Stop WSS and SQL services
- Copy content databases to new host
- Attach content databases in SQL
- Run `Test-SPContentDatabase -Name <DatabaseName> -WebApplication <URL>` to test custom components
- Run `Mount-SPContentDatabase -Name <DatabaseName> -DatabaseServer <ServerName> -WebApplication <URL> [-Updateuserexperience]` to register the database in SharePoint
- Verify content availability

There's additional considerations if you've got more than just content on your old server.  Provided you're on WSS 3.0 SP2 (a pre-migration requirement anyway), the [pre-upgrade checker](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc287628.aspx#section2) assists in determining those potential hiccups for you.